# Extjs Panel - Set click a button on tbar

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs4.1

I define a **'panel'** extend: 'Ext.form.Panel' that has a tbar with three buttons. 

when my other work done i want my 3nd button on tbar must click to do some task. 

I don't want create a new function with same task like panel.myfunction().

Any way to do that thanks

Comment: Please rewrite your question because it can hardly be told what your goal it.

Comment: I still don't understand what your goal is? Can you post some code?

Comment: Maybe, did you want a Handler on botton ? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler

Comment: example I want call button like function like panel.tbar[3].click :(

Comment: this link can help you: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?25677-2.0.1-fireEvent(-click-)-on-buttons-don-t-call-handler-function

Comment: I try but nothing work :(. panel.ttb.items.length not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be close to what you want:

```
panel.down("toolbar").items.items[3].handler();
```

If you really want the third visible button, I think instead of 3 you should be using 2 for the array index:

```
panel.down("toolbar").items.items[2].handler();
```

Comment: have other way to do like panel.toolbar.items.items[3].handler(); ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = this.down('button[action=save]');
button.fireEvent('click', button);
```